# Simplifying $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \sin ^{ 4 }{ x } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \sin ^{ 4 }{ 2x+\cdots+\frac { 1 }{ { 4 }^{ n } } \sin ^{ 4 }{ 2nx } })$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am unable to simplify this sum:

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left( \sin ^{ 4 }{ x } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \sin ^{ 4 }{ 2x+\cdots+\frac { 1 }{ { 4 }^{ n } } \sin ^{ 4 }{ 2nx }  }  \right)  } $$

I tried this by converting the sum into cosine using multiple angle formulae. But not able to simplify further.

Comment: Have you tried expanding $(e^{2kix}-e^{-2kix})^4$?

Answer (score 2):

Using $$\displaystyle \sin^{4}(x)=\sin^2(x)\cdot (1-\cos^2(x))=\sin^2(x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x)$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\sin^{4}(2x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}(2x)-\frac{1}{4^2}\sin^{4}(4x)$$..

In a similar way...

And last add all, You will get answer...